# AWS SDK for PHP - SQS error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

using the SDK, I can create a queue and get the queue list - but somehow I can not send message to any of the queues. Used the following:

```
$sqs = new AmazonSQS();
$sqs->set_region(AmazonSQS::REGION_SINGAPORE);
$queues =  $sqs->get_queue_list();
$response = $sqs->send_message($queues[0], $message);
```

But, I am getting the error:

```
[Type] => Sender
[Code] => AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue
[Message] => The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.
```

$queues is following: (xxxxx is a number)

```
    Array
(
    [0] => https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/1001xxxxxxxx/website-email
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the queue created? what is the value of $queues[0] ?

Comment: It has the queue URL. Updated the question with info.

Comment: Using the same SDK - `$sqs->create_queue('website-email')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. It seems to be a bug in SDK 1.5!

Check this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=82874&tstart=0

Quote from there:

> Users are experiencing problems when performing queue operations like
>   send_message and receive_message where an HTTP 400 error is received
>   with the error code AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue. This is
>   being caused by a regression introduced in version 1.5 of the SDK in
>   which the request URL for queue operations is not being constructed
>   properly.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the first parameter in `send_message()` is queue's name, not URI.

Comment: Name does not work as well. BTW - send_message takes URL. Source: documentation - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonSQS/send_message

Comment: I find the documentation confusing - it uses queue names in the examples instad of the URLs